# AWS IAM user receive 401 when accessing to ECR repository, works with root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I've started using AWS ECR to store my docker images. When I try to authenticate an IAM user, via Powershell (the same happens when I do via AWS command line) I receive a 401:UnAuthorized.
If I use the Auth key/secret of the root user, it works and authenticates.

The PowerShell script I use is

`(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 474389077978.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/myreoi`

I've replaced the AWS user with the IAM user. I've also added the IAM user to the admins, but it doesn't seem enough.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IAM user must be assigned a role to access the ECR service. This can be done by adding inline policy in the permission section of the groups.

Please follow the below steps to perform use non-root IAM users can perform docker ecr operation.

```
1.) Create IAM user say "ecr-user". 
2.) Create IAM group called "ecr-group".
3.) Add user ecr-user to ecr-group.
4.) Create a role "ecr-role"
5.) Attach the policy name "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole" to the role ecr-role.
```

---

```
6.) Go in the group section of the AWS console.
7.) Select the group "ecr-group" and go to the permission tab.
    Add policy - "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole" using attach policy button. 
8.) "Click here" in the inline policy section of the permission tab.
9.) Choose custom policy.
10.) Choose a name for custom policy - "ecr-passon"
11.) Add policy json given above - ensure to change your account id.

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "iam:GetRole",
        "iam:PassRole"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/ecr-role"
}]}
```

All these steps will attach the role ecr-role to the ecr-user of the group ecr-group with policy AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole.

AWS programmatic IAM users must assume a role to perform some operations.

Use the reference to understand the pass on the role.
[Pass a Role to an AWS Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html)

Comment: Excuse me ,I'm not able to find where should I put those information... under IAM ?

Comment: 1.) Create a role and add all the policies required to run the ECS services. -    Example role ecs-service-role is created in the image.https://imgur.com/DdQlk4P

2) Add inline policy for the group of iam user who is accessing ecs service. Use  above pass-on policy format given above. In place of "Resource" use ARN id of the role created in the previous step. See https://imgur.com/o6Rk86W for the place to add inline policy.

Comment: excuse me, but I feel dumb, To create the service you say, I've to go here https://imgur.com/97eZSg1, then what create role ,then what have I to choose ? https://imgur.com/Ats4AX3 , thanks again

Comment: Edited my answer with the steps, checked and it is working with non-root IAM user.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your explaination,I got this error ```Get-ECRLoginCommand : User: arn:aws:iam::325753xxxx:user/ecr-user is not authorized to perform:
ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username ecr-user --p ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...inCommandCmdlet:GetECRLoginCommandCmdlet) [Get-ECRL
   oginCommand], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.ECR.AmazonECRException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ECR.GetECRLoginCommandCmdlet```,thx

Comment: I have updated step 7 above - It should solve the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken error.

Comment: AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole was not just the previous one?

Comment: yes,  it is the same policy - you need to add this at two places. One in the role other in the group permission.

Comment: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken error simply means the IAM user running the application doesn't have the privileges required to run the service. The user has not acquired permission from the group and the role.

Comment: ok, but after having assigned it, to the user, group, do I have to wait some time or it's immediate? I've re-done each of your steps and I use this command ```(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username ecr/user --password-stdin xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com```

Comment: In my case it was immediately effective for the user.